# Why python3 is built native in yocto?

Tags: python, yocto

I am trying to compile python package for yocto and I found  python3 (python3.7) is  build native then it is cross compiled for arm architecture.I want to know why it is done like this in python.

Basically I want python3 binary should be available in recipe-sysroot and  recipe-sysroot-native directory . Right now it is available only in recipe-sysroot-native.

Thanks

William Jacob